# Disable Jenkins multibranch pipeline trigger on every commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline which is triggered after every commit, I want to disable every commit run and just set a trigger for a simple nightly test build

Answer (score 0):

You can set a CRON Job for this which will ensure that the Job will get triggered only once at the set time. Let's  assume that you need to run the build at 11 PM daily.

then following are the steps:

Under Build Triggers section

there is a option for Build Periodically enable it

```
0 23 * * *
```

Now this job will run every day at 11 PM or 23 hrs in the night.